# Fetch products with same price for last x days

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I would like to fetch those products that are reporting the same price for the last  5 days consecutively in MYSQL. I have attached sample data for your reference below.

```
PID Price   Date
P1  10  25-09-2018
P1  10  24-09-2018
P1  10  23-09-2018
P1  10  22-09-2018
P1  10  21-09-2018
P2  25  25-09-2018
P2  25  24-09-2018
P2  30  23-09-2018
P2  25  22-09-2018
P2  25  21-09-2018
P3  50  25-09-2018
P3  48  22-09-2018
P4  15  23-09-2018
P4  15  21-09-2018
```

The required output should be

```
PID Price
P1  10
P4  15
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the page [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and adjust yours accordingly. Primary it's usually expected that you add the code of your current efforts. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are using MySQL or Redshift? These are different systems and the answer might vary.

Comment: Why is `P4` included in your required output? It only appears in the input data for two days (21 & 23), which does not meet the requirement of "same price for the last 5 days consecutively".

Comment: Redshift is, of course, based on postgreSQL, not MySQL. So the two are very different. Please [edit] your tag to tell us which one. Please, also, tell us which version of the DBMS you use. It's relevant because more  recent versions have *window functions*, making this kind of query easier.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @John Rotenstein, P4 is included because in the last 5 days though I have only 2 entries the price did not change. Now I see that it  does not meet the requirement of "same price for the last 5 days consecutively"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data, you can try a query similar to the next pseudo-MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    Column_PID,
    Column_Price,
FROM
    the_table
WHERE
    Column_Date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY)
GROUP BY
    Column_PID, Column_Price
HAVING count(Column_Date) >= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

- Determine a "previous_price" for each `PID` and `date` (price on the previous date), utilizing [Correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html).
- Consider only data for last **5** days (this you can make it variable).
- Using [Derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and grouping on `PID`, filter (using `Having` clause), where `MIN` and `MAX` of the the change is 0.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT inner_nest.PID, 
       MAX(inner_nest.Price) AS Price 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t1.PID, t1.Price, 
         (SELECT t2.Price 
          FROM your_table AS t2 
          WHERE t2.PID = t1.PID 
            AND t2.date < t1.date 
          ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS previous_price  
  FROM your_table AS t1 
  WHERE DATEDIFF( NOW(), t1.date ) < 5
) AS inner_nest 
GROUP BY inner_nest.PID 
HAVING MIN(inner_nest.Price - inner_nest.previous_price) = 0 
   AND MAX(inner_nest.Price - inner_nest.previous_price) = 0
```